# How can I integrate Facebook into Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce

How can I integrate Facebook into Salesforce? I installed the free app [faceconnector](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0330000003z9bdAAA), but I am getting the error:

> Sorry, Faceconnector and Facebook are still working out some kinks. Please make sure you have added the custom field FacebookID__c to both the lead and contact Page Layouts. If that doesn't work, try again in a few minutes or try uninstalling and then reinstalling Faceconnector.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the FacebookID__c custom field as instructed?

If you can't get Faceconnector to work, you could also try the [Force.com Toolkit for Facebook](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Getting_Started_with_the_Force.com_Toolkit_for_Facebook) that was recently released as a beta.